# CRA Socket.io request returns net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

[image]

Hello. I've spent some time without luck trying to understand the problem here.

I've looked through each Question on StackOverflow which seems to deal with the same problem, though nothing has worked so far.

I have a simple chat app built using Create React App and Socket.io (which runs fine on localhost), but when deployed to my Node server I'm receiving `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` errors and no response. The website itself runs fine, but when I make a call to my Socket.io server, but errors.

I'm guessing this is down to my lack of knowledge with how Node and Socket.io want to work.

Some info:

**server.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http").createServer(app);

const port = 8080;

http.listen(port, () => console.log(`http: Listening on port ${port}`));

const io = require("socket.io")(http, { cookie: false });

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));
app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("New client connected");

  // Emitting a new message. Will be consumed by the client
  socket.on("messages", (data) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit("messages", data);
  });

  //A special namespace "disconnect" for when a client disconnects
  socket.on("disconnect", () => console.log("Client disconnected"));
});
```

**client.js**

```
....
const socket =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
    ? io("http://localhost:4001")
    : io("https://my-test-site:8080");

socket.on("messages", (msgs: string[]) => {
  setMessages(msgs);
});
....
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "X.X"
services:
  app:
    image: "my-docker-image"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        DEPENDENCY: "my-deps"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

**Dockerfile**

```
...
RUN yarn build

CMD node server.js // run my server.js
...
```

**UPDATE:** I got around this problem by making sure my main port was only used to run Express (with socket.io) - in my set up that was port: 8080. When running in the same Docker container, I don't think I needed to create and use the https version of the express 'createServer'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this problem by keeping just one port available (in my case `:8080`). This port is what `express/socket.io` is using (originally I had two different ports, one for my site, one for express). Also, in my case, when running in the same Docker container, I didn't require the `require("https").createServer(app)` (https) version of the server, as `http` was sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you forgot to map the port of your docker container. The expose statement in your dockerfile will only advertise for other docker containers, which share a docker network with your container, that they can connect to port 4001 of your container.

The port mapping can be configured with the `-p` flag for docker run commands. In your case the full command look somehow like this:

`docker run -p 4001:4001 your_image_name`

Also, do you have a signed certificate? Browser will likely block the conneciton if they do not trust your servers certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated my question with more info (https doesn't seem to make a difference). Also, I have a docker-compose.yml which has the ports defined, but I still get the same error. I'm afraid Docker doesn't make much sense to me at the moment. Would I need to run the `docker run -p 4002:4002 image_name` command during each deployment? Or just once during local development?

Comment: Thanks for adding the additional info. You would need to run the docker run command each time. You already have a compose file though and in that case the docker daemon will take care to resume your running docker-compose projects after restarts etc. Also your docker-compose spec looks fine.

Comment: Have you checked the docker logs of your node container? (`docker-compose logs -f`)

Comment: It just mentioned Server Side Rendering which shouldn't have any affect. I'm guessing it must be something to do with the server set up as I think from the above setup Socket.io *should* work.

Comment: Seems Dockerfiles' "CMD node server.js" command might not be working as I changed it to point to a script that didn't exist and it didn't error (I updated the initial question). Not sure why it's not failing.

Comment: the command specified with CMD wont throw errors while building the docker image, as it is only executed when the container is started. Did you check the log of you docker container? If your node server is not starting correctly, the error will be in there.

Comment: Also I've just noticed that there is no `io.listen(http)` call in your server code snippet. How are you initializing socket io? You should have a line like this in your code: `io = require('socket.io').listen(http)`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Eventually I got around the problem as I've marked in an answer, it was down to how I was setting up my server - it didn't seem to like me opening a new port.